# Reconnecting to CURRENT wifi with batch (with programming)

Tags: batch-file, wifi

one of my pcs has a faulty wificard so i wrote a batch script to reconnect to a specific network when its not receiving internet.
however i want to reconnect to the current network instead to a specified one

```
    quiet
    @ECHO OFF
    :loop
    
    Ping www.google.com -n 1 -w 1000
    if errorlevel 1 (
            netsh wlan connect #SPECIFIC SSID#
    ) else (
            timeout /t 1 /nobreak
    )
    goto loop
```

i hope someone knows a suitable solution with the use of BATCH

for further reference, i would like to get the lask connected wifi ssid so i can use the aforementioned script to reconnect me to that one instead of a set one.

Comment: SInce this is not a primarily programming related question, I suggest to move this to [SU]. How connecting to a different access point could **heal** a faulty hardware is above my head. I'd recommend to change the hardware.

Comment: @LotPings - I'd say "How do I programmatically determine the SSID of the wireless network I was most recently connected to" is at least somewhat on topic here.

Comment: @somethingDark yes that's what i wanted to do, i know this is 3 years ago but it might still prove useful to someone later on if answered.

Comment: `netsh wlan show wlanreport` might have what you're looking for, but I'm on a Desktop so I can't verify it.